# map custom Vim keybindings to NERDTree

Tags: vimrc, plugin-nerdtree

I am almost new to the Vim and I have this key mappings inside Neovim config.
that I want to be able to use inside NERDTree but I can't found a way.

```
nmap <c-j> 4j                                                                                                                 
nmap <c-k> 4k
nmap <c-h> 4h
nmap <c-l> 4l
```

Comment: If nerdtree sets the buffer name or filetype, you could use autocommands or an ftplugin. Note that C-j is also Enter (I think), C-h is usually also backspace, and C-l is usually for redrawing/clearing the screen.

Comment: my actual intent is to move faster between files. just by making the hjkl to jump four line

Comment: At that point, I find / (searching) faster

Answer (score 1):

You can set `autocmd FileType NvimTree nnoremap <buffer> <C-j> 5j` in your Vimrc.

And if you use Neovim you can set:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "FileType" }, {
  pattern = "NvimTree",
  callback = function()
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(0, "n", "<c-j>", "5j", { noremap = true, silent = true })
  end,
})
```